# Como escrever este SQL com Adonis query builder?

Tags: adonisjs

Olá, estou iniciando com Adonis e tenho problemas/dificuldade para montar uma query. 
Meu SQl simplificado está assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dtd.id_disciplina, dis.nome_disciplina
FROM  tbl_docente_turma_disciplina dtd, tbl_disciplina dis
WHERE dtd.id_ie = 1
AND  dtd.id_disciplina = dis.id_disciplina
```

Eu tentei algumas coisas como:

```
  const Table = Database.table('tbl_docente_turma_disciplina as dtd', 'tbl_disciplina as dis')

            return await Table
                        .distinct('dtd.id_disciplina', 'dis.nome_disciplina')
                        .where('dtd.id_ie', 1)
                        .where('dtd.id_disciplina', 'dis.id_disciplina')
```

Mas com erros:

```
 ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'dis.nome_disciplina' in 'field list'
```

Pelo que pude notar eu consigo acessar os campos do prefixo (dtd) mas não as do prefixo (dis)

Alguém pode me ajudar como escrever algo assim no Adonis? Obrigado!!

Comment: O que já tentou? Que dificuldades teve? Algum erro?

Comment: Acabei esquecendo de colocar meus testes. Atualizei meu post. Obrigado pelo retorno!

Comment: Aparentemente o Adonis não suporta produto cartesiano, é obrigatório o uso do JOIN

Comment: Putz, realmente eu demorei entender isso, acabei criando uma view no mysql pois não manjo muito de SQL para fazer esta adaptação. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você criou Models para cada uma destas tabelas? Se não pode fazer da seguinte forma:

**Disciplina.js**

```
'use strict'
const Model = use('Model')

class Disciplina extends Model {

  static get table() {
    return 'tbl_disciplina'
 }

 DocenteTurmaDisciplina() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/DocenteTurmaDisciplina', 'id_disciplina', 'id_disciplina')
 }
}
```

No model **DocenteTurmaDisciplina.js** da seguinte forma:

```
'use strict'
const Model = use('Model')

class Disciplina extends Model {

  static get table() {
    return 'tbl_docente_turma_disciplina'
 }
}
```

Sendo assim vc criará o relacionamento do Model com a tabela, e de Disciplinas com o nome dos docentes.

Sua consulta no controller ficará mais ou menos assim:

Já compreendendo que vc importou o os models

```
const Disciplina = use('App/Models/Disciplina')
const DocenteTurmaDisciplina = use("App/Models/DocenteTurmaDisciplina")
```

**Faça a query:**

```
const query = Disciplina.query()

query.with('DocenteTurmaDisciplina', (builder) => {
  builder.where('id_ie', 1)
})

query.distinct('tbl_docente_turma_disciplina.id_disciplina', 'tbl_disciplina.nome_disciplina')
```

A explicação disso está aqui:
https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_has_many

PS: nos models vc tem que por a Primary key no método primaryKey, verifique se vai precisar alterar isso nos models.

Até mais

Answer (score 0):

Testa dessa forma e vê se retorna algo

```
return await Database
    .table('tbl_docente_turma_disciplina')
        .innerJoin('tbl_disciplina',
                   'tbl_docente_turma_disciplina.id_disciplina',
                   'tbl_disciplina.nome_disciplina')
    }).where('tbl_docente_turma_disciplina.id',1)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas não deu certo